Utilizing Engineering Stack Exchange: Laplace Transform case study
I'm a new student to engineering. I've been investigating different means for learning material and investigating the discipline.  I'm already familiar with using different professional organizations for reading new articles and referencing past work.  Are there any suggestions engineering professionals would give regarding how to use this site?
For example, I'm currently learning about how crowd-sourcing can be used for developing technical documents and solutions.  A past challenge that I would use as a case study would be the following:
Last spring I was finding information for solving Laplace transforms.  There was plenty of information on sites like MIT-open Course-wear and in my e-textbook (Pearson).  However, I was once asked to proof the transform of e^x*cos(nx) by manual integration and online resources were limited.  There was some concept regarding commutativity that I believed was necessary for the proof but I could be incorrect.  Ultimately I struggled to utilize it in my final draft.  If solving these kinds of question are common on this
site please let me know and if someone has a method for proofing this problem I would really appreciate it.  Thanks!

Honestly, you should not need anything more than a good textbook. To the specific subject, Laplace Transform is used in electrical and control engineering, but the specific problem you're describing is more an exercise in performing an integration, so for that, check out Wolfram Alpha (online relative of Mathematica). It can automatically do step by step breakdown of standard mathematical problems. There is also math.stackexchange.com.

PS - this is more of a "meta" question -- https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com
